# Criar um Windows Service que chama um MVC

Tags: windows, mvc

Bom pessoal, eu ja tenho um projeto no modelo DDD, que é executado através de um projeto MVC, só que agora eu quero que aplicação seja executada como um serviço windows, tem alguma forma pratica para isso?

Metodo no MVC que quero iniciar é o Index:

```
 private readonly IAwbApplication _awbApplication;
    private readonly IMovimentoApplication _movimentoApplication;
    public static List<string> LogAplicacao = new List<string>();

    public AwbController(IAwbApplication awbApplication, IMovimentoApplication movimentoApplication)
    {
        _awbApplication = awbApplication;
        _movimentoApplication = movimentoApplication;
    }

    public void Index()
    {

        try
        {
            var movimentos = _movimentoApplication.ObterMovimentos();

            foreach (var movimento in movimentos)
            {
                var listaStatusWebServiceGol = _awbApplication.Pesquisar(movimento.nr_AWB.Trim()).ToList();
                var listaStatusMovimento = _awbApplication.StatusPorMovimento(movimento.id_Movimento);

                for (var i = listaStatusMovimento.Count(); i < listaStatusWebServiceGol.Count(); i++)
                {
                    listaStatusWebServiceGol.ToList()[i].id_Movimento = movimento.id_Movimento;
                    _awbApplication.InserirMovimentoTracking(listaStatusWebServiceGol.ToList()[i]);

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            GravarLogAplicacaoValidacao(ex);
        }

        finally
        {
            var log = new GeradorLogUtil();
            log.EscreverLog(LogAplicacao, @"C:\TrackingAwb\LogErro.txt");
        }


    }
```

Metodo Windows Service:

```
  public  void ExecutarRotina()
    {
        //AwbController.Index();
    }
```

Vale ressaltar que nao posso colocar meu metodo Index do vc como static

Comment: Sua pergunta esta um pouco subjetiva. Você tem uma WebApi e quer tornar-la um Windows Service?

Comment: @AndersonSouza a principio era uma aplicaçao web normal(porem nao tinha iteraçao nenhuma com o usuario) só que agora quero que isso rode como um windows service, então adicionei na minha solução um projeto do tipo windows service, ai não sei exatamente como para que aparti do windows service que estou criando ele execute o metodo que tenho no mvc, dar para entender? desculpe a dificuldade em explicar rs

Comment: Tranquilo,vamos la. A primeira coisa é determinar o gatilho para a chamada desse método, se for via projeto MVC, vc tem que refenciar o projeto Windows Service (WS) no projeto MVC. Se o gatilho for no projeto WS, vc tem que referenciar o projeto MVC no projeto WS. Para refenciar clique com o botão direito em 'References' > 'Add Reference..' > 'Projects' > 'Solution' > (e o projeto). Para usar o método declare o using (projeto referenciado) e o método a ser usado.

Comment: Sim fiz isso mas quando tento chamar o metodo Index por exemplo so consigo referencia-lo no windows service se ele estiver com static, mas nao  posso deixar ele assim, pq se nao vou precisar mudar todo o metodo do MVC e afetaria outras funcionalidades

Comment: Então ta facil rs, posta o metodo que vc esta chamando no MVC e como vc esta chamando ele no WS!

Comment: @AndersonSouza  coloquei o código na edição da pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu controller **AwbController** possui um construtor:

```
public AwbController(IAwbApplication awbApplication, IMovimentoApplication movimentoApplication)
{
    _awbApplication = awbApplication;
    _movimentoApplication = movimentoApplication;
}
```

Logo ao instância-lo vc devera passar os parâmetros exigidos **IAwbApplication** e **IMovimentoApplication** que aparentemente são uma Interface.

Então implemente essas duas interfaces na sua classe do Windows Service e tente isso:

```
 public void ExecutarRotina()
    {
        using (var awb = new AwbController(instanciaInterfaceIAwbApplication, instanciaInterfaceIMovimentoApplication))
        {
            awb.Index();
        }
    }
```

Comment: o unico problema é que o valor chega do outro lado como nulo, acredito que seja porque o AutoMapper esta configurado no Global.asax do MVC e quando chamo de outro lugar nao ocorre esse carregamento da configuração, teria com fazer apenas um "start" do MVC ou configurar o Automapper no windows service tbm?

Comment: Não saberia te dizer sem ver o projeto, mas creio que consiga sim.